# How to fix Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out

Tags: python, django

I am trying to change my user model to a custom one. I do not mind dropping my database and just using a new one, but when I try it to run makemigrations i get this error

```
bookings.Session.session_client: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
        HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.
```

booking/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from bookings.models import Session
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your views here.

def book(request, Session_id):
    lesson = get_object_or_404(Session, pk=Session_id)
    try:
        client = request.user.id
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'booking/details.html', {
            'lesson': lesson,
            'error_message': "You need to login first",
        })
    else:
        lesson.session_client.add(client)
         lesson.save()
     return HttpResponseRedirect("")
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #Custom apps
    'mainapp.apps.MainappConfig',
    'bookings.apps.BookingsConfig',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'mainapp.CustomUser'
```

bookings/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Session(models.Model):
    session_title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    session_time = models.DateTimeField("Time of session")
    session_difficulty = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    session_duration = models.IntegerField() 
    session_description = models.TextField()
    session_client = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.session_title
```

I'm trying to change the user model to abstractuser.

Answer (score 16):

include the following at in `views.py`

```
from django.conf import settings
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
```

and remove `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

Comment: Perfect solution..

Answer (score 13):

The problem is this line in booking/models.py:

```
session_client = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
```

You have a ManyToManyField to User, but you have set a different User model.

So in that field remove the import of User, add

```
from django.conf import settings
```

and change the model line to

```
session_client = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True)
```

Edit: there's another similar problem in views.py, as HenryM notes.

Answer (score 5):

Change:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

To:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
```

Answer (score 1):

because in settings.py is defined

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user.User'
```

instead of auth.User I added user.User

```
user = models.ForeignKey('user.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error,
Change model fields from this:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

to this:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(to=MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

MyUser is your custom user model