# Why does Django not find a field added to the AbstractBaseUser

Tags: django

I've inherited from the `AbstractBaseUser` as follows:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    """
    Main User model, inherits from AbstractBaseUser
    """
    # Meta
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length=60, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)  # equals to email
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    employee_of = models.OneToOneField(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

So each User is linked to one and only one Customer.

Now within a view I want to access the instance of the current logged in user within the `request` object and get the `employee_of` value to get a queryset that contains all users of that customer.

```
def render_employees(request):
    """
    Renders the employees page of the dashboard
    :param request:
    :return:
    """
    # Return the value for the current site for css specific classes
    dashboard_site = 'employees'

    # Query the employees
    qs_employees = User.objects.filter(employee_of=request.user.employee_of)  # doesn't find field

...
```

However the filter doesn't work because `request.user.employ_of` doesn't seem to return anything. My IDE even suggests e.g. `username`, `date_joined` etc. but not `employee_of`.

Why's that?

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    """
    A table that stores static data about a customer, usually a legal company
    """
    legal_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    street_number = models.CharField(max_length=3)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.legal_name
```

**Update:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager

from applications.customer.models import Customer

from django.conf import settings
BaseUser = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    """
    Main User model, inherits from AbstractBaseUser
    """
    # Relations
    user = models.OneToOneField(BaseUser, related_name='user_profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)  # link to default user model
    employee_of = models.OneToOneField(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

I linked the user to the default user model via Django admin. However in the view im still not able to access `employee_of` within `request.user`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that request.user is a different model. It's User model from `django.contrib.auth`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.

What you can do about it?
In our app we have `UserProfile` model that have OnetoOne relation to django `User`.
You can then store `employee_of` value there.

```
class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser):
    user = models.OnetoOneField("auth.User", related_name="user_profile", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    employee_of = models.OneToOneField(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

and then access `request.user` employees using something like

```
request.user.user_profile.employee_of
```

Comment: hm that still doesnt seem to work. I added the relation to the default user model using this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55780537/how-to-fix-field-defines-a-relation-with-the-model-auth-user-which-has-been-s since the string in your solution returned an error.